# Way to speed up ngFor when using a filter?

Tags: javascript, angular, performance, filter, ngfor

I'm trying here to reproduce an example from a project where I have to show a big list of string names without using pages, just a scroll.

Because of the high number of values to show the speed of the filter is not very fast, specifically when you add some string filter and you start to remove that filter, the cursor do not move immediately and smoothly in the filter, so for the user its not very responsive.

String name can vary a lot, from 3, 4, 5 characters up to around 32 characters

The list can grow to around 10 000 items (result of a search for items)

So far I have this demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xg6dqt?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

I've generated (pseudo) random names.

I've tried to debounce the call to the function using `(keyup)="debounce(applyFilter(),700)"` but it did not help, it means when I try to remove or add something to the filtering string the cursor stops to write time to time until a result is displayed.

It's more quick in this example, but in my applications, since I do have many components and services, it looks more slow than this example.

Is there a way to make this filter more responsive ?

**app.component.html**

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Angular filter for big array
</p>

<input type="text" placeholder="filtering string here" [(ngModel)]="filterString" (keyup)="applyFilter()"/>

<h2>Array</h2>

<table style="max-height:400px;height:400px;overflow-y:scroll;">
  <tbody style="display:block;max-height:400px;height:400px;width:400px;overflow-y:scroll;">
    <tr *ngFor="let item of filteredItems">
      {{item}}
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 5';

  items:string[]=new Array();
  filteredItems:string[]=new Array();

  filterString:string;

  ngOnInit(){
    for(let i=0;i<10000; ++i)
      this.items.push(Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 24)+Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 24)+"1234567899*xxx");
    this.filteredItems=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.items));
  }

  applyFilter(){
    this.filteredItems= this.items.filter((item) => {
      return item.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(this.filterString) > -1;
    });
  }
}
```

**Note:**

Due to the way the change detection works in angular, I've removed the use of [angular pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes), because its even more slow with that, so I decided to filter directly my array in the component TS code.

Comment: Have you considered adding infinite scrolling or virtual scrolling?   The performance problem can be rendering all 10,000 DOM elements

Comment: I've found some links talking about that, but didn't find the way to implement it using observables or something else, because I'm already using observables when handling client state. its a little bit slow to get response, so I considered that it can be more slow for a scroll in my case.

Comment: rendering 10,000 items is definitely the issue, i would look into infinite scrolling or just showing the top 50 matches

Comment: How to handle the filter if I show just a small number, because the filter has to be done over the 10 000 items to get a new array to render. I've already tested the sort it took 0.091 seconds (displaying sorted items). will test the filter time depending of the filtering string size to see. The first rendering took a small time (about 1 to 2s), but when applying the filter and displaying the result at the same time, that gives definitely a bad performance.